# JDeveloper: AnnotatedNoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I have created a new Java Application in JDeveloper. That application only uses the `Java` application. No `Swing` and no `ADF` technologies are used.

I have created a new class with a static main method.

When I'm trying to compile the project, this error is shown:

```
Error: Exception thrown during compilation: oracle/classloader/util/AnnotatedNoClassDefFoundError
```

I'm trying to find on Google any reference of this, but each page that I see talks about `ADF`.

Anybody knows how to fix that issue?

Edit: the class code:

```
package wewe;

public class Class1 {
    public Class1() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is for new development, you really don't want to bother with JDeveloper. There are much better (and free) alternatives.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't choose the IDE.

Comment: what's in your static main method? Do you mind posting it here?

Comment: The static main method is empty. It only creates a new instance of the main class.

Comment: Nitz, is the main class big? Maybe worth posting it here, so others can have a look and maybe help find something?

Comment: Ok, I will edit the OP in a few moments.

Comment: Not much in the main class either. Is it the only file in your project? The error suggests that there is a missing class. I guess your project probably is missing some jar file which is referenced? Is there more error details actually produced by JDeveloper?

Comment: There isn't any other file in the project, and JDeveloper only shows this error.

Comment: As there is no code error, I guess it could be JDeveloper installation/configuration error. It is unfortunate you cannot choose IDE,otherwise Eclipse is much better. Sorry I couldn't help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I didn't installed correctly the JDK, and JDeveloper didn't reported. Now all works.